# Why can I not cast a lambda to void* then to a function pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a special case where I need to cast a lambda to void* in order to store it due to type erasure.

Everything works as expect for the first case but not the second and I'm wondering how to solve it and if this behavior is even defined to start with.

```
int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](int x){
        std::cerr << x << std::endl;
    };

    //Cast lambda to void*
    void* vptr = static_cast<void*>(&lambda);

    //Cast vptr back to lambda and call it
    (*static_cast<decltype(&lambda)>(vptr))(10); //<--- Ok, compiles and works

    //Cast vptr to function pointer
    (*static_cast<void(**)(int)>(vptr))(10); //<--- Compiles but segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `void(*)(int)`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't. I'm writing a delegate class which can store basic function pointers, member function pointers and lambdas. I still want it to be as fast as possible and doing it any other way won't work.

Comment: A lambda is not a function.  In rough terms, it is a functor (a structure with an `operator()`).   Converting it (or its address) to a function, and then calling that function gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Dr.Jones You've thought of every other possible way? Doubtful. Plenty of the standard library itself can do what you're describing and it doesn't need to hack things to `void*` to do so. Try to do less of the "I can't" and do more of the "I'll think about how I can"!

Comment: @Peter thank you mate, that answered my question. Was wondering why the second example didn't work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit for this specific case there is almost no other way, you are welcome to write a class like that yourself. I use the first example in my code though so I always know its type through template parameter.

Comment: I am almost certain that, whatever you're trying to do, you do not need to do it like this. Open your mind to new possibilities!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here you go, https://github.com/nilosweden/Delegate is using a void* a bad idea here?

Comment: Add some documenting comments to your code if you want me to read it. :)

Comment: @Dr.Jones: Just based off the name, is `std::function` what you really want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lambda is not a function — it is an instance of a hidden class type with a `operator()` member. So, casting the address of your lambda to a function pointer is never going to work.

Either use your first method (which works) or, preferably, change things around so that this requirement evaporates altogether. Because it's insane.

Comment: Thank you, that also answered my question

Comment: Didn't know it was a competition. I can upload the code so you can look at it yourself and tell me how to solve it in a better way.

Comment: *So, casting the address of your lambda to a function pointer is never going to work*. Actually it works for non capturing lambdas. As an example `using fn = void(*)(); fn f = [](){}`. The lambda decays to a function pointer in this case.

Comment: @skypjack: That is not the same thing; that is a straightforward conversion, not pointer aliasing.

Answer (score 4):

Non capturing lambdas decay to function pointers, as an example:

```
#include<functional>

int main() {
    using Fn = void(*)();
    using Fnp = void(**)();
    Fn fn = [](){ };
    Fnp p = &fn;
    (*p)();
}
```

Capturing lambdas do not.
In your case, you can exploit this feature.

Comment: Yes, thats why I asked the question, I though i could cast a non-capturing lambda to a function pointer, but that doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: It actually decays to.